# How to get form data parameters from ContainerRequestContext

Tags: java, rest, jersey, form-submit, jersey-2.0

I have used Jersey 2 to expose functionality (restful API).

Where I want to access form parameter at filter level, the way we have accessed `pathparam`,`queryparam` from `ContainerRequestContext.

Filter:-

```
public class SecurityFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter
{
  private ResourceInfo ResourceInfo;

    // ignore this
    public SecurityFilter(ResourceInfo ResourceInfo)
    {
       
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext ctx) throws IOException
    {
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> pathparam = ctx.getUriInfo().getPathParameters();
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryparam = ctx.getUriInfo().getQueryParameters();
      // Here I want all form parameters 
    }    

    // ignore this     
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException
    {

    }    
}
```

So how can I get the form parameters from `ContainerRequestContext` in above filter?

---

**EDIT :**

I have one way to get form data is

```
((ContainerRequest) context).bufferEntity();
// Read entity
FormDataMultiPart multiPart = ((ContainerRequest) context).readEntity(FormDataMultiPart.class);
String myValue =  multiPart.getField("foo").getValue();
```

But this won't work for large file because `((ContainerRequest) context).bufferEntity()` contain entity in memory so `Exceptionorg.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` exception occur.

Comment: For large entities, you need to manually buffer the entity into a temp file and then replace the entity stream to point to a stream that would read the entity from the temp file. There is no other off-the-shelf support in Jersey for this use case at this point available, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

See my comment to your [issue opened against Jersey](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2664?focusedCommentId=381362&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-381362).

Essentially you have already answered your question in the edited text. And, unfortunately, in case you need to deal with very large entities, you need to do the heavy lifting (buffering & processing & serving & cleanup of the entity stream) manually at the moment.